# Date int to string (0 --> Sun, 1 --> Mon, etc)

Tags: java, jsp

Have the following which reads a date from my SQL and returns the day of the week as a number.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(rs.getDate("ShipmentDate"));
int DayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

This works fine.

How can I convert the result (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) into (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat)?

The example I pinched the above code from mentioned using an array, although gave no example.

Comment: Locale based `Map<Integer, String>`

Comment: [`Calendar#getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName(int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String[] days = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};`

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(days[0]); //--> "Sun"
System.out.println(days[1]); //--> "Mon"
```

and so on...

**In your example:**

```
int DayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

String dayString = days[DayOfWeek];
```

Answer (score 0):

`String[] dayToString = {
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
}`

later

`int day = ...;
String strDay = dayToString(day);`